# How to get specific xml format in Web Api MVC having specific namespace

Tags: c#, asp.net, asp.net-mvc, asp.net-web-api, xml-parsing

I have a class which is sent at response in WebApi MVC. The XML format which is sent is :

```html
<Employee xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" xmlns:xsd="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema" p3:schemaLocation="https://www.company.com/xsd/input.xsd" xmlns:p3="https://www.company.com">
    <p3:Id>101</p3:Id>
    <p3:Name>Mickey</p3:Name>
</Employee>
```

But I would like to have as :

```html
<Employee xmlns:xsi="https://www.company.com" xmlns:xsd="https://www.company.com/XMLSchema" xsi:schemaLocation="https://www.company.com/xsd/input.xsd">
    <Id>101</Id>
    <Name>Mickey</Name>
</Employee>
```

The class is as below :

```
[DataContract(Namespace = "https://www.company.com")]
Class Employee {
[DataMember(Order = 1)]
[XmlElement(Namespace = "https://www.company.com")]
public int Id { get; set; }

[DataMember(Order = 2)]
[XmlElement(Namespace = "https://www.company.com")]
public string Name { get; set; }
}
```

What shall I do/change to achieve this?